# Как проверить hover через jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно чтобы при наведении на элемент в одном блоке, добавлялся класс элементу из другого блока и удалялся если курсор "уходит с элемента".

Вот мой пример, который я пытался реализовать, но он почему-то не работает должным образом:

```js
$('.tab1').hover(function() {
  $('.block-1').addClass('block-tab-1');
}, function() {
  $('.block-1').removeClass('block-tab-1');
});

$('.tab2').hover(function() {
  $('.block-1').addClass('block-tab-2');
}, function() {
  $('.block-1').removeClass('block-tab-2');
});

$('.tab3').hover(function() {
  $('.block-1').addClass('block-tab-3');
}, function() {
  $('.block-1').removeClass('block-tab-3');
});
```

```css
div[class*=block-tab] { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-1">
  Этому блоку должен добавляться класс при наведении на .tab1, .tab2 или .tab3.
</div>

<div class="block-2">
  <a href="" class="tab1">Tab 1</a>
  <a href="" class="tab2">Tab 2</a>
  <a href="" class="tab3">Tab 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: я в вашем коде добавил стиль для добавляемого класса (цвет при наведении для наглядности), все работает. Также добавил ссылку на `jquery` в сниппет ибо он не выполнялся

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.tab1').hover(function() {
  $('.block-1').addClass('block-tab-1');
}, function() {
  $('.block-1').removeClass('block-tab-1');
});

$('.tab2').hover(function() {
  $('.block-1').addClass('block-tab-2');
}, function() {
  $('.block-1').removeClass('block-tab-2');
});

$('.tab3').hover(function() {
  $('.block-1').addClass('block-tab-3');
}, function() {
  $('.block-1').removeClass('block-tab-3');
});
```

```css
.block-tab-1 {
  color: red;
}

.block-tab-2 {
  color: green;
}

.block-tab-3 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-1">
  Этому блоку должен добавляться класс при наведении на .tab1, .tab2 или .tab3.
</div>

<div class="block-2">
  <a href="" class="tab1">Tab 1</a>
  <a href="" class="tab2">Tab 2</a>
  <a href="" class="tab3">Tab 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш пример прекрасно работает. Можете наглядно посмотреть: [Пример тут](https://codepen.io/ihutornoy/pen/JJajjV)

```
.block-tab-1 {
  background: yellow;
}

.block-tab-2 {
  background: blue;
}

.block-tab-3 {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: А есть альтернативный скрипт на hover? Этот вариант не очень подходит, он срабатывает даже если курсор уже находится на элементе - скрипт запускается заново.